# Formula not consistent with showing result

Tags: excel, excel-formula, bloomberg

I have the following formula:

```
=IF(BDH(CONCATENATE($AA8;" Index");"PX_LAST";BL8;BL8;"days=a";"fill=p")>$BE8*$AC8;0;1)
```

It shows me if the index is above or below a certain price, and then measures it with a fixed number in my sheet.

It works sometimes, but then for no reason it gives an `#N/A` error.

For some reason when I put a `'` before the formula and then erase the `'` again the formula starts working again.

Does anyone have any idea how I can fix this?

It does not have anything to do with my Bloomberg connection.

Comment: It seems the `BDH` is the issue, nothing else other than that could produce the behaviour you described.

Comment: Put the `BDH` expression in a separate cell and see what error you get. It could be an incorrect ticker or date etc.

Comment: BDH doesn't seem to be the issue. Whenever I write the formula again it seems to work for a short while

Comment: The item in menu Formulas / Evaluate formula is a utility you can use to track where the `#N/A` is coming from. Maybe you could post a screenshot of the 1st step it appears (before it gets propagated anywhere else). From what I see, except if `AA8`, `BL8`, `BE8` or `AC8` themselves have a #N/A (do they contain formulas too?), I can only see the `BDH` as the most probable cause as well.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I changed the `BDH Formula to BDH($AA9&" INDEX"; "PX_LAST";BJ9;BJ9;"days=a";"fill=p")`, and that seemed to do the trick.